# Как отправить Cookie в заголовке запроса

Tags: php, curl, cookie

Копаюсь с сайтом фмс - http://services.fms.gov.ru/info-service.htm?sid=2000
Как я понял, сначала заполняется форма POST, сохраняются куки и идёт редирект на страницу - http://services.fms.gov.ru/info-service-result.htm?sid=2000 с GET параметром sid=2000, но в заголовке запроса присутствую куки.

Вот POST запрос, где отлично сохранятся куки рядом с исполнительным файлом

```
    $connection = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_URL, "http://services.fms.gov.ru/info-service.htm?sid=2000");
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['DOC_NUMBER'        => '1111', 
                                                  'DOC_SERIE'            => '123123',
                                                  'form_name'=> 'form',
                                                  'captcha-input' =>$res
                                                ]);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, __DIR__ . "/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ . "/cookie.txt");
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $res=curl_exec($connection);
    curl_close($connection);
```

куки:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_services.fms.gov.ru   FALSE   /   FALSE   0   JSESSIONID  f5029a49e24c7d0c741d69255161
services.fms.gov.ru FALSE   /   FALSE   0   uid wwg+fltDaHdWFwsCC+8UAg==
```

Потом обращаюсь к странице - GETом

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://services.fms.gov.ru/info-service-result.htm?sid=2000');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ . "/cookie.txt");
$out = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

но куки не видит.

PS. Возможно я не правильно высказываюсь в плане передачи кук в заголовке запроса. отладчик мне вот что говорит: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы инициализируете curl, сохраняя значение в `$curl`, а затем устанавливаете куки для `$connection`.

Нужно заменить `$connection` на `$curl` вот в этой строке:

```
curl_setopt($connection, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, __DIR__ . "/cookie.txt");
```

Comment: ничего не изменилось